# Seek bar set custom min Value

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am using seek bar in android  which will have the min value as 25 and Maximum value as 85 .

I an setting the Min and Max value in XML , and When i a trying to set min value , it is saying , it is available from API 26  and mine min API is currently 19 .

**XML**

```
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/mySeekbar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:max="85"
            android:min="25"
            android:progress="25" />
```

**JAVA**

```
mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                if (seekBar.getProgress() < 25) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(25);
                }
               // Log.i("Progress","Dimming"+(110-seekBar.getProgress())+"Prgress :"+seekBar.getProgress());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

In the On Change Method I am Restricting seekbar at 25 Progress Level . but UI is not looking good , is it possible to Move start position when 25 is min value . [ Supporting API 19 ]

[image]

Comment: Calculate relative values on progress change between 25 to 85 and keep the `SeekBar` from 0 to 100 . That means for you 0% is 25 and 100% is 85 . And set the step size accordingly .

Comment: Thanks for the Comment , Trying to Do the same . @ADM

Answer (score 1):

From 25 to 85 so 
Its equal to from 0 to 60

So You can just calculate difference (-25) in Your values and don't use setMin in XML.